# Понятна запятая перед вторым тире, но зачем перед первым?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, вставная-конструкция, запятая-перед-тире

Нашел пример из справочника Розенталя:

> Прежде чем мы расстанемся, — а некоторые из нас вернутся сюда, быть может, не скоро, — прежде чем мы расстанемся, я хотел бы ещё раз вернуться к только что сказанным словам о нашей дружбе.

Почему запятая стоит перед первым тире? Части одинаковы, но всë же должна, по-моему вставка в начало относиться. Или не к началу?

Вставка относится к обоим частям или к первой? Ни пойму. Если к первой, зачем там запятая тогда?